# Java Date to UTC using gson

Tags: java, json, date, gson, utc

I can't seem to get gson to convert a Date to UTC time in java....
Here is my code...

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").create();
//This is the format I want, which according to the ISO8601 standard - Z specifies UTC - 'Zulu' time

Date now=new Date();          
System.out.println(now);       
System.out.println(now.getTimezoneOffset());
System.out.println(gson.toJson(now));
```

Here is my Output

```
Thu Sep 25 18:21:42 BST 2014           // Time now - in British Summer Time 
-60                                    // As expected : offset is 1hour from UTC    
"2014-09-25T18:21:42.026Z"             // Uhhhh this is not UTC ??? Its still BST !!
```

The gson result I want and what I was expecting

```
"2014-09-25T17:21:42.026Z"
```

I can clearly just subtract 1hr before the call toJson but this seems to be a hack. How can I configure gson to always convert to UTC ?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

After some further research, it appears this is a known issue. The gson default serializer always defaults to your local timezone, and doesn't allow you to specify the timezone. See the following link.....

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=281

The solution is to create a custom gson type adaptor as demonstrated in the link:

```
// this class can't be static
public class GsonUTCDateAdapter implements JsonSerializer<Date>,JsonDeserializer<Date> {

    private final DateFormat dateFormat;

    public GsonUTCDateAdapter() {
      dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.US);      //This is the format I need
      dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));                               //This is the key line which converts the date to UTC which cannot be accessed with the default serializer
    }

    @Override public synchronized JsonElement serialize(Date date,Type type,JsonSerializationContext jsonSerializationContext) {
        return new JsonPrimitive(dateFormat.format(date));
    }

    @Override public synchronized Date deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement,Type type,JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) {
      try {
        return dateFormat.parse(jsonElement.getAsString());
      } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new JsonParseException(e);
      }
    }
}
```

Then register it as follows :

```
  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new GsonUTCDateAdapter()).create();
  Date now=new Date();
  System.out.println(gson.toJson(now));
```

This now correctly outputs the Date in UTC

```
"2014-09-25T17:21:42.026Z"
```

Thanks go to the link author.

Comment: What do I do if I need it to be static?

Comment: Not sure why you said the class cannot be static. It can be. I'm using it as a static class.

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` isn't threadsafe. You could get in big trouble with that... In many cases this shouldn't really have any impact, if you just are aware of this fact.

Comment: If you could extend to include *commons-lang3*, you can use a thread-safe formatter i.e., [FastDateFormat](https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/FastDateFormat.java)

Answer (score 4):

The Z in your dateformat is in single-quotes, it must be unquoted to be replaced by the actual timezone.

Furthermore, if you want your date in UTC, convert it first.

Comment: It is valid ISO8601. If you convert it to UTC first, SimpleDateFormat will put a Z there, otherwise the Offset. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: So the Z in the dateFormat should probably be XX

Comment: Without the Z in quotes gives "2014-09-25T18:17:21.026+0100" which is the correct time but not UTC. Z without quotes just adds the timezone +0100. I need the output to be the UTC time and read exactly "2014-09-25T17:21:42.026Z"

Comment: You have to convert the date object to the UTC timezone first. Can you give gson a DateFormat object instead of a string? since you can tell a SimpleDateFormat object its timezone with `sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));`

Comment: Don't use `XX` but `XXX` only.

Answer (score 2):

The solution that worked for me for this issue was to create a custom Date adapter (P.S be carefull so that you import `java.util.Date` not `java.sql.Date`!)

```
public class ColonCompatibileDateTypeAdapter implements JsonSerializer<Date>, JsonDeserializer< Date> {
private final DateFormat dateFormat;

public ColonCompatibileDateTypeAdapter() {
  dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ") {
        @Override
        public StringBuffer format(Date date, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos) {
            StringBuffer rfcFormat = super.format(date, toAppendTo, pos);
            return rfcFormat.insert(rfcFormat.length() - 2, ":");
        }

        @Override
        public Date parse(String text, ParsePosition pos) {
            if (text.length() > 3) {
                text = text.substring(0, text.length() - 3) + text.substring(text.length() - 2);
            }
            return super.parse(text, pos);
        }
    };


}

@Override public synchronized JsonElement serialize(Date date, Type type,
    JsonSerializationContext jsonSerializationContext) {
  return new JsonPrimitive(dateFormat.format(date));
}

@Override public synchronized Date deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type,
    JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) {
  try {
      return dateFormat.parse(jsonElement.getAsString());
  } catch (ParseException e) {
    throw new JsonParseException(e);
  }
}}
```

and then use it while creating GSON object

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new ColonCompatibileDateTypeAdapter()).create();
```

Answer (score 1):

I adapted the marked [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26046107/1121497) and parametrized the `DateFormat`:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;
import com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive;
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializer;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Date;

public class GsonDateFormatAdapter implements JsonSerializer<Date>, JsonDeserializer<Date> {

    private final DateFormat dateFormat;

    public GsonDateFormatAdapter(DateFormat dateFormat) {
        this.dateFormat = dateFormat;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized JsonElement serialize(Date date, Type type, JsonSerializationContext jsonSerializationContext) {
        return new JsonPrimitive(dateFormat.format(date));
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized Date deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type,JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) {
        try {
            return dateFormat.parse(jsonElement.getAsString());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new JsonParseException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers were working for me in Kotlin so I did my own implementation:

```
val SERVER_DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" // Adjust as per your use case

val gson = GsonBuilder()
    .setDateFormat(SERVER_DATE_FORMAT)
    .registerTypeAdapter(Date::class.java, object : JsonSerializer<Date> {
        private val utcDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(
            SERVER_DATE_FORMAT,
            Locale.ENGLISH
        ).apply {
            timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
        }

        // Avoid using local date formatter (with timezone) to send UTC date
        override fun serialize(src: Date?, typeOfSrc: Type?, context: JsonSerializationContext?): JsonElement {
            return JsonPrimitive(src?.let { utcDateFormat.format(it) })
        }
    })
    .create()
val gsonConverterFactory = GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)

val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("Your URL")
    .addConverterFactory(gsonConverterFactory)
    .build()
```

I hope this can be useful for somebody else!

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). So TBH I hope that this will be useful for no one else.