# Gson mess up with minute value

Tags: java, timestamp, gson

I am using gson to convert serialized message to object, but I have problem with converting one attribute to `java.sql.Timestamp`

The start time attribute in JSON is

```
{...other_fields, "start_time": "2020-05-27 05:23:43.022610"}
```

And my Gson parser is initialized this way

```
new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S").create();
```

The object is parsed properly, but the start time has different minutes and seconds values as it should. The result of parse start time is: `2020-05-27 05:24:05.61`

What am I missing?

**Edit1**:

> Java Version: `1.8`
>      Gson version: `2.8.2`

**Edit2**:

> After change format to `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` (omitting
>   milliseconds) I got the right result, but without milliseconds value.
>   I can live with that, but it would be nice if someone could still
>   explain this issue.

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26044881/java-date-to-utc-using-gson can help you to understand that.

Comment: Well, with one `S`, `022610` is apparently interpreted as 22610 milliseconds. Your expected time plus 22610 milleseconds equals the result you get.

Comment: @Maede This guy is experiencing timezone offset shift. I could solve that. My problem is that minutes, seconds, and milliseconds are totally messed up

Comment: @MCEmperor yes it looks like it is this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`GsonBuilder.setDateFormat()`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.2/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#setDateFormat-java.lang.String-) uses `SimpleDateFormat`.

And [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) doesn't support microseconds during parsing. `S` denotes miliseconds, which means only 3 places after the decimal.

This can be proved. In your JSON remove microseconds and use `2020-05-27 05:23:43.022` as input.

Output would be

> 2020-05-27 05:23:43.022

`Timestamp` does support microseconds and if you want to convert `2020-05-27 05:23:43.022610` (with microseconds) to `Timestamp`, you are better off writing a [custom GSON deserializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096940/how-do-i-write-a-custom-json-deserializer-for-gson)

**Edit : Sample deserializer for Timestamp**

```java
class TimestampDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Timestamp> {

    @Override
    public Timestamp deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        // Handle null checks or format check, etc.
        return Timestamp.valueOf(json.getAsString());
    }
}
```

Usage:

```java
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().registerTypeAdapter(Timestamp.class, new TimestampDeserializer()).create();
```

Comment: I tried to use it with only 3 digits after decimal point and i was working as you said. Timestamp deserializer works like a charm as well. Thank you